# How to restrict negative values with onkeypress and onpaste

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to restrict input field which will not allow negative(-) values onkeypress and paste function. I have tried the below code.
But could not resolve this.

```
if ((event.which == 17 || event.which == 86) && event.which == 189) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

```js
$("input").keypress(function (event) {
        if (event.which == 45 || event.which == 189) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }).on("paste", function (event) {
       // console.log("event------>", event);
        if ((event.which == 17 || event.which == 86) && event.which == 189) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Side note: there are other ways to input data beyond key pressing and pasting, for example I can drag text into the field or use an autofiller. You should use the `input` event to catch all types of input instead of listening on certain specific types of input... (Also, pasting doesn't have a key code, of course)

Comment: @CherryDT You meant to say  "pasting doesn't have a key code"?

Comment: Yes - I'm confused, didn't I write literally that, letter by letter? 

Answer (score 0):

this might not be perfect but hope it helps

```js
$("input").bind("change keyup input paste", function(event) {
  // console.log("event------>", event.which, $(this).val());
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/-/g, ""));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control">
```